# Reading/Writing multiple datasets to a single HDF5 file

Tags: java, hdf5

How can we write multiple datasets to a single HDF5 file?
Similarly, how could these datasets be re-read from the same file?

I was thinking of creating multiple datasets using groups.. The code below is attempting to **create an opaque datatype using ScalarDS under a group**, but it is throwing exceptions.

```
      public static void createFile(Message message)throws Exception{  
      // retrieve an instance of H5File
      FileFormat fileFormat = FileFormat.getFileFormat(FileFormat.FILE_TYPE_HDF5); 
      if (fileFormat == null){
      System.err.println("Cannot find HDF5 FileFormat.");
      return;
      }   
      // create a new file with a given file name.
      H5File testFile = (H5File)fileFormat.create(fname);    
      if (testFile == null){
      System.err.println("Failed to create file:"+fname);
       return;
        }   
      // open the file and retrieve the root group    
        testFile.open();
        Group root = (Group)((javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode)testFile.getRootNode()).getUserObject();
        Group g1 = testFile.createGroup("byte arrays", root);        
    // obtaining the serialized object   
       byte[] b =serializer.serialize(message);  
       int len=b.length;
       byte[] dset_data = new byte[len+1];
   // Initialize data.
       int indx=0;
       for (int jndx = 0; jndx < len ; jndx++)
       dset_data[jndx] = b[jndx];
       dset_data[len] = (byte)(indx) ;
   // create opaque dataset ---- error here…
       Datatype dtype = testFile.createDatatype(
       Datatype.CLASS_OPAQUE, (len*4), Datatype.NATIVE, Datatype.NATIVE);
       Dataset dataset = testFile.createScalarDS
       ("byte array", g1, dtype, dims1D, null, null, 0, dset_data);//error shown in this line
  // close file resource
     testFile.close();
}
```

}

I fail to understand why is it giving me HDF5 Library Exceptions and points at the createScalarDS line. Why is it unable to create an opaque dataset under the group?

Answer (score 0):

The default configuration doesn't allow it but you can check out [Parallel HDF5](http://www.hdfgroup.org/hdf5-quest.html#phdf5) which supports parallel write access via MPI.
However this does only work with uncompressed data.

Comment: Hii Umit...thank you for the help but one problem does exist.. Parallel HDF5 is not supported with java..

Comment: Is it possible to write multiple datasets in a group? Can this be done dynamically?

Comment: @kuki
Yes Java wrappers don't support parallel HDF5. 
it is possible to write multiple datasets into a group however it's only possible to write to the HDF5 file from one thread. However you can write from one thread and read from any other thread at the same time. What do you mean with dynamically?

Comment: Well, in my program code, I call this 'public static void rec(Message message)' from another class; where message is an object of the Message class which is later serialized. message is actually a JMS message which the user inputs. I wish to tap down all the messages sent by the user to one HDF5 file but under different opaque datasets, with each message stored in one dataset.Since I will not have an idea as to how many words the user would input, I need all of these dataaset creation to happen at runtime depending on the number of words the message object consists.

Comment: @kuki: I haven't used the JAVA wrapper for HDF5 but I recommend to post your exception to the hdf5 mailing list (HDF Users Discussion List <hdf-forum@hdfgroup.org>). They are usually quick in responding to such issues.